Worker thread is started multiple times when running Dash App
I'm trying to (a) have a worker thread that does some background work and (b) to monitor its progress using Dash. For some reason, when executing the code, the script is loaded twice, and two worker threads end up running. The code below reproduces the situation.
import threading
import time
from threading import Thread

from dash import Dash, html

print("Load script")


def worker():
    print(f"Worker started; Thread {threading.get_ident()}")
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f"Thread {threading.get_ident()}, iteration {i}")
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Dash("App")
    app.layout = html.Div([html.Div(id='dummy')])
    worker_thread = Thread(target=worker)
    worker_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True)

The output is:
Load script
Worker started; Thread 6179811328
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app 'App'
 * Debug mode: on
Load script
Worker started; Thread 6121779200
Thread 6179811328, iteration 0
Thread 6121779200, iteration 0

As the output shows, the script is loaded a 2nd time, and another worker thread is created. I wonder why and how I can prevent it.

I can't give you the exact "why", but it has to do with the "debug-mode" turned on by dash/flask. On start up, it starts the whole application twice, running your main-script twice, thus, in your case creating two threads printing each iteration.
It can be turned off with app.run(debug=False).
Please note: if you run the application in a different way, (i.e. with flask run) make sure you use the appropriate flags there to disable/enable the debug-mode as well.

That indeed changes the behavior so that only one worker threat is running.
